# Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore 5.12.3 - CLOBs are returned as null

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-core, clob

How can I read a CLOB column using Oracles Entity Framework core (latest version)?

I have tried this (from https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-data-access-components/19.3/odpnt/EFCoreLargeCharacter.html):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Email>()
            .Property(a => a.Body)
            .HasColumnName("BODY")
            .IsUnicode(false)
            .HasColumnType("CLOB");
```

and this:

```
[Column("BODY", TypeName = "CLOB")]
```

It always returns null!  How can I populate the CLOB?

```
var emails = await context.Emails.ToListAsync();
context: public DbSet<Email> Emails { get; set; }
```